# Помогите с настройкой потоков

Tags: python, многопоточность

Есть функция parser():
Её должны выполнять 2 потока
То есть:
Потоки запускаются одновременно берут разные данные из файла там строки и все смотрят их и записывают ответ, и вот у меня не получается найти как запустить эти потоки.
Проще говоря 2 потока надо сделать чтобы они выполняли одну функцию одновременно и зависеть они в принципе не должны но не должны брать 1 и туже строку, помогите пожалуйста не получается найти решения.

Comment: Делается это для ускорения чекера

Comment: Ваш код увидеть можно?

Comment: А сами потоки тяжеловесные, что-то запускают, или только считают? Если только считают и ничего им не нужно отдельно грузить, то проще через `multiprocessing.Pool` распихать строки по потокам и собрать результат. Самим потокам при этом вообще не нужно думать как делить данные, они просто получают свою порцию, обрабатывают и отдают результат.